# Can you put multiple elements in an html a tag?

Tags: html, href

Very newbie question.

For instance, is this okay?

```
<a href="allaboutpeanuts.html">Peanuts<img src="peanut.jpg"> </a>
```

I tried it and it works fine, but I've been googling around and I can't find any mention of anyone putting more than one element in an a href.  So are you not actually supposed to do that, but I cheated, so it's sort of a hack?

Comment: Unrelated, but make sure you include the required `alt` attribute on your `img` tag. It should be `<img src="peanut.jpg" alt="Peanut" />` The `alt` attribute is used for anyone who can't see images (whether because they're turned off or the visitor has a visual disability).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, absolutely. HTML tags can be nested in any combination and any number.

The main rule is that they must ***nest*** properly. So this is **not** valid:

```
<a href="allaboutpeanuts.html">Peanuts <h1>Lovely <img src="peanut.png" alt="Peanut" /></a> Peanuts</h1>
```

The `h1` tag is not completely inside the `a` tag.

This, however, is entirely valid:

```
<div><h1><a href="allaboutpeanuts.html">Peanuts <img src="peanut.png" alt="Peanut" /></a></h1></div>
```

Comment: And also remember the self-closing tags like `img`. Those cannot contain other elements.

Answer (score 5):

This is perfectly valid HTML, just note the following constraints:

In HTML 4.01 and XHTML, only inline elements are valid as children of an `<a>` tag (e.g. `<span>`)

In HTML5, this has been changed to allow non-interactive block level elements - e.g. you can nest `<p>`, `<div>`, `<h1>` or even `<section>`, but not a further `<a>` or `<input>`. [See [The a element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element)]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's correct - you can place one element into another. The only illegal thing is to place block elements inside inline elements.